# Good way to writing unit test in python

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-unittest

I have simply 'to do' app in python 2.7 and I wrote for this some unit test. This is my first time with python unit test and I just wanna to know idea of unit test.

1. Someone can tell me whether I'm going in the right direction?
2. How to improve this tests?
3. How to check message in IndexError is correct? for this ("*IndexError('**Note doesn\'t exist**')*" or IndexError('**Returned more then one entry**') )

App:

```
# coding: utf-8
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from shutil import copyfile
import json
import os

DATABASE = 'notes_data/notes.json'
BOARDS = ['to do', 'in progress', 'done']


class NotesManagerMixin(object):

    def count(self):
        return len(self.notes)

    def filter(self, *args, **kwargs):
        result = self.notes
        for key, value in kwargs.iteritems():
            result = [
                note for note in result
                if getattr(note, key, None) == value or 
                note.message.startswith(str(value)) or 
                note.message.endswith(str(value))
            ]
        return NotesQueryset(result)

    def get(self, *args, **kwargs):
        notes = self.filter(*args,**kwargs)
        if notes.count() == 0:
            raise IndexError('Note doesn\'t exist')
        elif notes.count() == 1:
            return notes[0]
        else:
            raise IndexError('Returned more then one entry')

    def first(self):
        return self.notes[0]

    def last(self):
        return self.notes[-1]


class NotesQueryset(NotesManagerMixin):

    def __init__(self, notes):
        self.notes = [note for note in notes]

    def update(self, *args, **kwargs):
        for note in self.notes:
            for key, value in kwargs.items():
                setattr(note, key, value)
            note.save()
        return self



    def delete(self):
        for note in self.notes:
            note.delete()
        return self


    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        return self.notes[idx]

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.notes)

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.__str__()


class NotesManager(NotesManagerMixin):

    def __init__(self):
        self.notes = []

    def __iter__(self):
        return self.next()

    def __generate_id(self):
        """
            Funkcja pomocnicza do pobrania pewnej wolnej wartości indexu.
        """
        try:
            return max(note.id for note in self.notes) + 1
        except ValueError:
            return 1

    def all(self):
        return NotesQueryset(self.notes)

    def add(self, idx, board, message):
        self.notes.append(Note(idx=idx, board=board, message=message))

    def create(self, board, message):
        note = Note(
            idx=self.__generate_id(),
            board=board,
            message=message
        )
        note.clean()

        self.notes.append(note)
        note.save()

        return note

    def next(self):
        for note in self.notes:
            yield note

    def to_dict(self):
        return [note.to_dict() for note in self.notes]


class Note(object):
    objects = NotesManager()

    def __init__(self, idx, board, message):
        self.id = idx
        self.board = board
        self.message = message

    def __str__(self):
        return 'ID: {}, Board: {}, Message: {}'.format(
            self.id,
            self.board,
            self.message
        )

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.__str__()

    def clean(self):
        if not self.message:
            raise ValueError('Message is required')

        if self.board not in BOARDS:
            raise ValueError('Board "{}" doesn\'t exists'.format(self.board))

        if type(self.id) != int:
            raise ValueError('Note id "{}" is invalid'.format(self.id))

    def save(self):
        for key, note in enumerate(self.objects):
            if note.id == self.id:
                self.objects.notes[key] = self
                break

        with open(DATABASE, 'w') as database_file:
            json.dump(self.objects.to_dict(), database_file, indent=4)

        return True

    def delete(self):
        for key, note in enumerate(self.objects.notes):
            if note.id == self.id:
                self.objects.notes.pop(key)

        with open(DATABASE, 'w') as database_file:
            json.dump(self.objects.to_dict(), database_file, indent=4) 


    def to_dict(self):
        return {
            'id': self.id,
            'message': self.message,
            'board': self.board
        }


def load_initial_data():

    with open(DATABASE, 'r') as database_file:
        json_data = json.load(database_file, encoding='utf-8')

    for item in json_data:
        Note.objects.add(
            idx=item['id'],
            board=item['board'],
            message=item['message'],
        )


load_initial_data()
```

unit tests:

```
import unittest
from notes_manager_v2 import NotesQueryset, Note, load_initial_data, NotesManagerMixin

class TestNotesQueryset(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_filter(self):
        actual = Note.objects.all().filter(board='in progress') # get all notes with board 'in progress'
        expected = []
        for note in Note.objects.all():
            if note.board == 'in progress':
                expected.append(note)
        self.assertItemsEqual(actual, expected)

    def test_get(self):
        actual = [Note.objects.all().get(id=1)] # get note with method get
        expected = []
        for note in Note.objects.all(): # search note with index 1
            if note.id == 1:
                expected.append(note)
        self.assertEqual(actual, expected)

    def test_get_fail_1(self):
        self.assertRaises(IndexError, lambda:Note.objects.all().get(id=9868976)) # thos note dont exist should raise IndexError


    def test_update(self):
        from_board = 'to do'
        to_board = 'done'
        before_change = Note.objects.filter(board=from_board) # use filter method to get all notes with board 'to do'
        actual = Note.objects.filter(board=from_board).update(board=to_board) # update all board 
        self.assertNotEqual(before_change, actual) # check for difference
        notes = Note.objects.all()
        for note in actual:
            self.assertIn(note, notes) # check notes are updated 



    def test_delete(self):
        to_delete = Note.objects.filter(id=2).delete() # find note with filter method and delete it 
        notes = Note.objects.all()
        self.assertNotIn(to_delete, notes) 


    def test_create(self):
        new_note = Note.objects.create(message='lorem ipsum', board='in progress') # create new note
        notes = Note.objects.all()
        self.assertIn(new_note, notes) # 






if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the documentation? See [doctest](https://docs.python.org/2/library/doctest.html). They are an easy way to integrate unit tests into python code. Another option is the [unittest](https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html) framework.